# How do I modify the coefficients of a logistic regression model in Weka?

Tags: logistic-regression, weka

I have previously trained a logistic regression classifier on the Iris data set, and saved the resulting model to a file named `iris.model`.

I now load the model into the Weka Explorer:

[image: Logistic regression model loaded into Weka]

How do I edit the coefficients of this model? For example, I want to change Iris-setosa's `sepallength` coefficient from 21.8065 to 19.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Weka's classifiers are data driven and don't offer post-build fine-tuning or manual modifications.